# Looking for how to save a cxgrid layout (devexpress) using StoreToStorage

Tags: delphi, devexpress

Using Delphi, cxgrid (Devexpress), I need to save the layout in the database. I have functions to save using ini file, but this create many files in and want to save these settings in the database.

To do it I was thinking to use StoreToStorage, saving on the database in string. Or if I do not find I have to put this ini file in the database...

Anyone has a example using StoreToStorage?

Example with INI file - save

```
procedure TFrm_BI_Exemplo.actDoSaveExecute(Sender: TObject); 
begin 
 inherited;  
 grdPadraoCxDBTableView1.StoreToIniFile(ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName) + '/filtros/Teste.ini', true, [gsoUseFilter, gsoUseSummary]); 
end ;
```

Exemplo com INI file - Load

```
procedure TFrm_BI_Exemplo.actDoLoadExecute(Sender: TObject);
begin        
 inherited;  
 grdPadraoCxDBTableView1.RestoreFromIniFile(ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName) + '/filtros/teste.ini', true, false, [gsoUseFilter, gsoUseSummary]);
end;
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

All the Views (`TcxDBTableView` in your case) have the method `StoreToStream`. You can put an stream into a blob field in your Database and use `RestoreFromStream` to restore the `ViewState`.

I just don't understand what you're doing here:

```
grdPadraoCxDBTableView1.RestoreFromIniFile(ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName) + '/filtros/teste.ini, true, false, [gsoUseFilter, gsoUseSummary]);
actCancLoad.Execute;
cbbCarregarNome.Text := 'Selecionar Arquivo';
```

Seems like you are loading an ini file and then canceling the load... review this code.

Comment: About the `storetostream` that it's not working here... I think that I need to understand better how to use. I did it both codes (save / restore): ... `AStream : TMemoryStream;` ... `AStream := TMemoryStream.Create;` It is working: `ClientdatasetNAMEOFTHEFIELD.LoadFromStream(AStream)`; Here it is not working: `ClientdatasetNAMEOFTHEFIELD.SaveToStream(AStream); //It's not loading to Astream...` I will paste better the code. Do you have some example code to me try?

Comment: I ask this because I tried to search the Internet but I didn't find a code using StoreToStream as a example...
like `grdPadraoCxDBTableView1.StoreToStream(AStream);`
Thanks about your time!

Comment: var
      msTest: TMemoryStream;
    begin
      msTest := TMemoryStream.Create;
      try
        msTest.SaveToStream(oConfAd);
      finally
        FreeAndNil(msTest);
      end;  
    end;

Comment: OK tks, but I suspect that the problem is related to size... Because I am looking here the differences between ini file created by `StoreToIniFile` and the result of the `  cdsBIConfigCONFILT.LoadFromStream(AStream);` then `cdsBIConfigCONFILT.AsString` and they look different (ini has many more data). 

`cdsBIConfigCONFILT //is a Tmemofield.`

Comment: I created the memo as a test: `CREATE TABLE TC_BICONFIG (
    CODFILT INTEGER NOT NULL,
    CONFILT BLOB SUB_TYPE 1 SEGMENT SIZE 10000 CHARACTER SET WIN1252);
ALTER TABLE TC_BICONFIG
ADD CONSTRAINT PK_TC_BICONFIG
PRIMARY KEY (CODFILT);
`
(firebird) and maybe I can create it different configuration. 

I am testing here(some times I need stop to do another things...).

Comment: Humm, I think that it will save me: (https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q246978) and this [example](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Attachment/GetAttachmentFile/85f4f5b9-289e-4ca3-b8d8-0936292586c9), I need just do it but using clientdataset.